# List of arguments of structures

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, fold

Since I am fairly new to racket I stumbled across a problem I could not solve.

To break it down, I have a list containing several structures of the same type, and I want to create a list with only one specific argument of each elements structure. Something like this:

```
(define-struct sample (name number))
(define samples (list (make-sample "A" 1) (make-sample "B" 2)))
```

So when apply the function to this list I get the following list:

```
(lit "A" "B")
```

I want to solve this problem without recursion, only using lambda expressions and map and fold.

I tried to get access to every elements argument by using:

```
(foldr sample-name samples)
```

But that does not work.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!
Appa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `map`, please take a look at the documentation to understand the difference between [`foldr`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) and [`map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29).

```
(map sample-name samples)
=> '("A" "B")
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tried that and edited my question, I appreciate your help.